# Strange error: TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to train a VAE model. However I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/devcharaf/Documents/Uni/UdeM/Internship/newGNN/app/train.py", line 28, in <module>
    trained_model, loss = train(model, train_data, optimizer, num_epochs=1000, model_type="VAE")
  File "/Users/devcharaf/Documents/Uni/UdeM/Internship/newGNN/app/utils.py", line 322, in train
    recon_x, mean, logvar = model(data["x"], data["edge_index"])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/pygeometric/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/devcharaf/Documents/Uni/UdeM/Internship/newGNN/app/model.py", line 47, in forward
    mean, logvar = self.encoder_forward(x, edge_index)
  File "/Users/devcharaf/Documents/Uni/UdeM/Internship/newGNN/app/model.py", line 53, in encoder_forward
    x = self.encoder(x, edge_index)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/pygeometric/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I tried many combinations of arguments but nothing seems to work. Can you spot the error?
As you can see in the following model, the forward function was called in the train() function with only two arguments and not 3. Also the error hints at the line self.encoder(x, edge_index). But when I try to remove one of these arguments, I get an error saying not enough arguments.
Here is my model:

```
# Variational Auto Encoder
class VAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_dim, hidden_dim, latent_dim):
        super(VAE, self).__init__()
        self.in_dim = in_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            gnn.GCNConv(in_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            gnn.GCNConv(hidden_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.fc_mean = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, latent_dim)
        self.fc_logvar = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, latent_dim)
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            gnn.GCNConv(latent_dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            gnn.GCNConv(hidden_dim, in_dim),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        mean, logvar = self.encoder_forward(x, edge_index)
        z = self.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
        recon_x = self.decoder_forward(z, edge_index)
        return recon_x, mean, logvar

    def encoder_forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.encoder(x, edge_index)
        mean = self.fc_mean(x)
        logvar = self.fc_logvar(x)
        return mean, logvar

    def decoder_forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.decoder(x, edge_index)
        return x

    def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * logvar)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return eps.mul(std).add_(mean)
```

and here is my train function:

```
def train(model, data, optimizer, num_epochs):
    model.train()
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    beta = 1
    epoch_losses = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Output of the model
        recon_x, mean, logvar = model(data["x"], data["edge_index"])
        output = recon_x
        kl_loss = -0.5 * torch.mean(1 + logvar - mean.pow(2) - logvar.exp())
        kl_loss *= beta
        kl_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

        target = torch.zeros(data["num_nodes"], 1)

        # Loss computation
        loss = criterion(output, target)
        loss += kl_loss

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_losses.append(loss.item())
    
    return model, epoch_losses
```

Here is the code I am using to train the model:

```
model = VAE(in_dim=10, hidden_dim=32, latent_dim=8)

# Create an instance of the optimizer.
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Train the model for a specified number of epochs.
trained_model, loss = train(model, train_data, optimizer, num_epochs=1000)
```

Comment: _the forward function was called in the train() function with only two arguments and not 3_ Do you know what the asterisks in `forward_call(*input, **kwargs)` mean?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, it means that you can pass a variable number of non-keyword arguments! However I feel like I am giving my forward function the right number of arguments

Comment: Exactly.  So you can't really say "it was called with only two arguments".

Comment: @devCharaf It means each element of the iterable `input` is passed as a *separate* argument. Don't confuse the similar syntax used in the *definition* of a function to accept multiple arguments with the syntax for *passing* multiple arguments in a function *call*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    def encoder_forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.encoder(x, edge_index) # 3 inputs self, x, edge_index
```

`encoder` is just a `nn.Sequential`.
For Sequentials the forward is defined as [follows](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/container.html#Sequential) - which can only take two arguments - and should be the root of the error.

```
def forward(self, input):
        for module in self:
            input = module(input)
        return input
```

---

While a bit of a hassle to solve your problem write your forward method for encoder and decoder layer wise.

I dont know about the special layers you use and what output they produce so
at best you can do something like:

```py
for module in self.encoder:
   x = module(x, edge_index)
```

Probably you need an extra if statement if you hit the ReLU.

---

Sureway would be to do the forward pass manually

```py
def __init__(self, in_dim, hidden_dim, latent_dim):
    ...
    self.enc_conv1 = gnn.GCNConv(in_dim, hidden_dim)
    self.enc_relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.enc_conv2 = gnn.GCNConv(hidden_dim, hidden_dim)
    self.enc_relu2 = nn.ReLU()
    ...

def encoder_forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.enc_conv1(x, edge_index) # I dont know how these layer work and what output they produce
        x = self.enc_relu1(x)
        ... 
        logvar = self.fc_logvar(x)
        return mean, logvar
```

Comment: while this seems to be working, it makes the Sequential() option completely irrelevant. Isn't there a way to call directly the Sequential Layer? I guess the problem would be the ReLU that takes only 'x' while the GCNConv takes two args

Comment: I hardly doubt it because of how the forward function is defined. But you could make your own subclass of Sequential and write your own forward function. e.g. with a `if isinstance(module, GCNConv)`  to pass 2 or just 1 parameters.

Comment: I used the for loop at the end with the if statement ```if isinstance(module, GCNConv)``` and ```else```. Thanks